# matplotlib. как отобразить в качестве подписей на оси x все значения из столбца dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

matplotlib. ось x сформирована из значений столбца, которые являются строками. plot() рисует график, в котором в виде подписей на оси x представлены только некоторые значения столбца (в данном примере через один). как отобразить все значения исходного столбца?

```
d = {'string': ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'], 'f1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 'f2': [3, 6, 8, 5, 2, 7, 12, 6, 7, 10, 4, 6, 13, 15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.plot(x ='string', y =['f1', 'f2'], kind='line', figsize = (15.5, 6.5))
```

Comment: Вы можете привести в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных? График нужен в виде линии или столбчатой диаграммы?

Comment: спасибо за уточнение. график нужен в виде линии. 'bar' отражает каждый элемент столбца, а 'line' через один

Comment: @MaxU, добавила

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте после `df.plot(...)`:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df)), df['string'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]